# How to change the background color in Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How to change the background color in Visual Studio Community 2017? I selected the "dark" theme, but the background still white.

[image: visual studio]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studion 2017 - Tools \ Options \ Environment\ Fonts and Colors \ Show Settings for dropdown. Modify the color in the item background.

Answer (score 0):

whoever checks this in 2019- it changed a bit: go to tools: code-->preferences-->Color Theme. You can pick any color needed